# Problem auto mapping => collection of view models instead another view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I have something like this

```
public class AViewModel
{
    public decimal number { get; set; }
    public List<BViewModel> BVM { get; set; }
}

public class BViewModel
{
    public string someString{ get; set; }
}

public class SomeObject
{
    public decimal number { get; set; }
    public List<OtherObjects> BVM { get; set; }
}

public class OtherObjects {
    public string someString{ get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<SomeObject,AViewModel>();
```

When I have this I get

- Trying to map OtherObjects to BViewModel
- Using mapping configuration for SomeObject to AViewModel
- Destination property: BVM
- Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
- Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.

How can I help it figure out how to map it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a typeconverter between OtherObject and BViewModel by specifying a [custom type converter](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters&referringTitle=Home)

Here's what the converter would look like:

```
public class OtherToBViewTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<OtherObjects, BViewModel>
{
  public BViewModel Convert(ResolutionContext context) 
  {
    if (context.IsSourceValueNull) return null;

    var otherObjects = context.SourceValue as OtherObjects;

    return new BViewModel { someString = otherObjects.someString; }
  }
}
```

And then the map would be called like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeObject,AViewModel>().ConvertUsing<OtherToBViewTypeConverter>();
```

Comment: This seems like overkill to me, Automapper should be able to handle this case just by mapping the other 2 types.

Comment: obviously it can't the error message is clearly stating that automapper needs help converting between the types.  this is one way to convert between types, there may be another way, but the above code will work.  it's like 8 lines so i don't think it's that bad.

Answer (score 5):

I believe Automapper needs to know how to convert OtherObject to BViewModel. Try adding a mapping for that too.