# Automapper to map child list properties

Tags: c#, automapper

Im trying to map a viewmodel to a domain that looks like the following:

**domain**

```
public class Category
{
     public int CategoryId {get; set;}
     public List<Product> Products {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{

    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

**viewModel**

```
public class CategoryVM
{
     public int CategoryId {get; set;}
     public List<ProductVM> Products {get; set;}
}

public class ProductVM
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
}
```

Then this automapper code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryVM, Category>();
Category category = Mapper.Map<CategoryVM, Category>(_category);
```

It throws the error on the `Products` property:

`Trying to map WebUI.ViewModel.ProductVM to Domain.Product.
Using mapping configuration for WebUI.ViewModel.ProductVM to Domain.Product Destination property: 
Products Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.`

Im guessing I'm mapping child properties wrong or something? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem auto mapping => collection of view models instead another view model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691270/problem-auto-mapping-collection-of-view-models-instead-another-view-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also need a map from ProductVM to Product

Automapping is finding these properties match but doesn't know how to map them and forth.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create [Custom Type Converters](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters&referringTitle=Home)

Similar question: [Problem auto mapping => collection of view models instead another view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691270/problem-auto-mapping-collection-of-view-models-instead-another-view-model)

Comment: Man...If automapper cant do this automatically, whats the point of it?

Comment: Automapper was never designed to go from VM => Domain and is best used to go from Domain to VM.